# CakePHP 4 update extra field on HABTM join table

Tags: join, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have the problem that I want to UPDATE an existing record/ extra field in the joinTable of a belongsToMany association in the controller by first loading the models like this:

```
SomeController.php

$query = $this->Object1
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Object2'  => [
            'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q)  use ($object2_id) {
                return $q->where(['Objects2.id' => $object2_id]);
            }
        ]
    ])
    ->matching('Object2', function ($q) use ($object2_id) {
        return $q->where(['Object2.id' => $object2_id]);})
    ->where(['Object1.id' => object1_id]);
                
    $user = $query->first();
```

Then I update one field in the joinData:

```
SomeController.php
    $object1->objects2[0]->_joinData->status = 1;
    $this->usersTableObj->save($object1)
```

Result: the field is not updated, nothing happens.

As it took me a day to find the solution (use setDirty()) I want to share it with you:

```
SomeController.php
    $object1->objects2[0]->_joinData->exampleField = 1;
    $this->usersTableObj->save($object1)
    $user->setDirty('objects2', true);
```

But I also wonder if my way is the right approach (the query feels super expensive) to update the joinTable record? Or would you rather go for a simple "unlink"/ "link"? But then how to insert joinData field content?

Thanks
Christian

Comment: It really depends, for example, do you need to use the additional data somewhere, for example show it to the user? And how do you know that you need to update the first entry in the list of _n_ associated records that share the same object ID? Can there only be one associated record maybe? Or do you maybe have a specific sort order configured for the association that you rely on?

Comment: Hi ndm, 
- yes the additional data is used (it is actuall a user-user n:m friendship relationship, in the joinTable is the status (requested, confirmed,...).
- therefore each Object1:Object2 relationshipitself is also unique,that is how I know that I always can take the first (and only) item.

Comment: Just so there's no misunderstanding, by "_additional data_" I mean the `Object1` data, as your concern was the query. If you don't need _that_ data, then you could just query and save the join table record directly.

Comment: Object1 data is not really used. However, how would I access the data of the join table record directly? 
"$this->Objects1->JoinTable->find()" or "$this->Objects2->JoinTable->find()" leads to an association error.

Comment: It would be `$this->Objects1->Objects2->junction()->find()`, here `Objects2` will be an association instance (`\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany`), and `junction()` will return the table instance that represents the join table.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about junction() - that would indeed save me quite a lot of DB reads and php calculations. Will try,thanks!